# Miner and Validator, who can validate a contract?

Tags: blockchain, verify, contract-verification

I am still confused with the process from creation to validation of transaction or contract verification. Actually the terminology makes me confused such as voter, validation, miner, honest node, fraud node, peers who are related with validation and so on.

What is a validation and verification of transaction? I have tried to find any information of them, but it is not a clear information.

My question is that after mining, who will verify and/or validate this transaction and if so, who can be a validator. Is a validator a honest node? 
Who can decide a honest node or fraud node. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mining :**

The ethereum main net uses, untill now, the Proof of work as a mechanism of getting the blocks(transactions inside) agreed upon and added to the blockchain.

The proof of work requires the nodes in the network to do some work in order to prove their "will to be part of the network". working and succeeding in completing the task is rewarded by currency to the winners, that is mining (basically working hard to find gold/coins).

**Voter :**

Voter nodes can be anything, i have no idea what a voter is in the current ethereum implementation. In other blockchain implementation like quorum, voter nodes can have multiple meanings : voters can vote to add or not new validators in a proof of authority mechanism.

**Validation :**

validation is the fact of making sure all the participants(fully working not light nodes) agree that a certain node in the network can create the next block and recieve the reward. in PoW the Validation is when a request of validation of the results of the work of a certain node is broadcated to the network in order to see that the results are genuin.

**Honest node :**

An honest node is basically a fully working node with no intentions of creating false transactions or malicious blocks. It is a node that follows rules.

**Fraud node :**

a node that doesn't follow the basic rules, a node that sends false transactions, a node that trys to attack the network, ...

Comment: If I wanted to be a voter in ethereum, how can I be a voter. Can I know the process to be a voter.

Comment: What do you mean by "voter"? In what context did you see this word used? (e.g. In an article?)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks  think i had a typo there. I encountered voters, when working with quorum where it can have an impact on choosing wether to add an other block maker

Comment: I think that node who can participated in validation work for new block is valid or not is a voter or validator as I found till now. So, actually a validator is more understandable terminology than a voter. Because a voter meaning makes us confused in between quorum and validating blockchain.

Comment: @JongH Well yeah , i got that confusion for sometime and i ahd to read about quorum to be able to understand it. i will change my answer to better fit this.